# NET Core and Angular polyfills can't be loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have hosting on IIS and I created folder Web.
So now url to my application looks like that: `http://x.xxx.example.com/web`
And there is a problem with loading js needed by Angular that are added in `dist/index.html`:

```
GET http://x.xx.example.com/polyfills-es2015.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://x.xx.example.com/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://x.xx.example.com/main-es2015.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When application where were placed directly in wwwroot folder there was no problem.

This is `dist/index.html` generated by Angular:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FtblrApp</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Files are attached in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
 "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
```

---

my files:
[image]

Comment: Are you bundling with custom webpack configuration alongside Angular one?

Comment: I don't have webpack file, this project is generated from Visual Studio when we choose Angular and .NET Core MVC Web application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you did not set the `basehref` in your index.html.

Replace `<base href="/" />` with `<base href="/web/" />` (if "web" is the folder containing your app), then build the app again and it should work.